# Meaning of react file extension in Jest React tutorial

Tags: javascript, reactjs, babeljs, jestjs

I am working through the Jest React tutorial for testing React components. The tutorial creates a Link React component; I'm unclear on the file extension of the file it is written in :

[image]

How does the .react file extension work? Is it comparable to .jsx, or someway to namespace files that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a convention some people use instead of .jsx extension but it still highlights it's a .js file that is intended to be a React component.

Answer (score 0):

The extension that matters is the one after the last dot (in this case .js, so it is a javascript file).

You could concatenate as many dots as you want (Link.react.another.name.js) as far as at the end you have the right extension